# Dialogflow telephony transfer call using webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, telephony, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to integrate dialogflow transfer call using webhook.

I tried with this

```
const response = {
  fulfillmentMessages: [
    {
      platform: "TELEPHONY",
      TelephonyTransferCall: {
        phone_number: "+1*************",
      },
    },
  ],
};

agent.add(
  new Payload("GOOGLE_TELEPHONY", response, {
    rawPayload: true,
    sendAsMessage: true,
  })
);
```

but its not working. Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Hi @sariga ms, Could you provide any error message if you are facing ? Meanwhile, have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/phone-gateway#transfer) and let me know if this is helpful for you or not.